# Rollup with d3 namedExports issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rollup, rollupjs, es6-modules

I have a package I am making which uses d3. Of course, in my `rollup.config.js` file I declare `d3` as both an external and global package:

```js
let config = {
  ...,
  output: {
    external: ['d3'],
    globals: {d3:'d3'},
    ...,
  },
  ...
}
```

and I might have a function in a file somewhere like:

```js
import * as d3 from 'd3'
...

export function someFunc(arg1, arg2) {
  d3.select(arg1)
  d3.min(arg2)
}

...
```

and when I bundle my code with `rollup -c` I get the nice warning that

```
src/modules/some-file.js
selection is not exported by node_modules/d3/dist/d3.node.js
```

so I go back to my `rollup.config.js` file and add the following:

```js
// inside config
plugins: [
  ...,
  commonjs({
    ...,
    namedExports: {
      'node_modules/d3/dist/d3.node.js': [
        'selection', 'min',
      ]
    },
    ...,
  })
  ...,
]
```

and now my bundle has no warnings or complaints... but when I go to use my bundled code, I get errors like:

```js
TypeError: d3_node_1 is null 
TypeError: d3_node_2 is null
```

where `d3_node_1` appears where I have `d3.select` in my code and `d3_node_2` appears where `d3.min` is.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to use the [rollup-plugin-node-resolve](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-node-resolve) to use third party modules from node_modules

Comment: I have ```nodeResolve({
      mainFields:['jsnext', 'main'],
    }),
```

Comment: Probably  you have to configure it like nodeResolve({ mainFields:['jsnext', 'main'], jsnext: true })

Comment: `Error: node-resolve: do not use deprecated 'module', 'main', 'jsnext' options with 'mainFields'`

Answer (score 1):

adding `'module'` to `mainFields` seemed to solve it

```js
  nodeResolve({
      mainFields: [
        'module',
        'main', 'jsnext'
      ]
    }),
```